# I can't rotate a point in my curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Here's what happens when I try to rotate the curve, hopefully it will be easier to understand:

[image]

Is there any way I can rotate this part on the Y-axis so the road is horizontal?

Thanks for anwsering!

**EDIT:** Problem solved, thanks to @lemon! I simply had to use CTRL+T to twist my curve

Comment: Probably the handles are set to "auto". Have a look at the tools panel in the curve section and set it back to "free", for instance

Comment: @lemon Just tried this, still the same problem...

Comment: Upload your file, that can help to understand the issue. Please use this link to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Done: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4718/ :)

Comment: OK, I understand now. You cannot rotate along this axis (as it is the road axis). What you need to do is to twist the curve: use Ctrl+T instead of R.

Comment: You can also use the information panel (N) where you'll find the same parameter named "tilt".

Comment: Didn't knew about this option! Thank you very much :)